# How to run a webView.evaluateJavascript with asynchronous javascript?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to run some asynchronous (via callback or Promise, I'm trying both) Javascript from Android and I can't find a way to do it.

Is there a standard way to do it that I'm missing from the docs?

code:

```java
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
  String GetSomething  = "javascript:GetSomething()"; // GetSomething returns a Promise
  webView.evaluateJavascript(GetLocationListing, new ValueCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("CONSOLE RECEIVED THE", s); // Null
      }
  });
}
```